# Get two different attributes from an Xml File

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextreader

I have an Xml File that looks like this:

```
<Head>
<Node Name="something" value="10"/>
<Node Name="somethingElse" value="3"/>
</head>
<Head>
<Node Name="something" value="10"/>
<Node Name="somethingElse" value="3"/>
</head>
```

What I want is to be able to create and object that contains two Objects which have a name and a key.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void XmlReaderMethod(string Path)
{
SomeObject object = new Object();
 using (XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(Path))
            {
                while (xReader.Read())
                {
                    if (xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute)
                    {
                        if (xReader.Name == "Name")
                        {
                            object = new object(xReader.Name);

                        }
                        else if (xReader.Name == "Value")
                        {
                           object.Key = xReader.Name;
                        }
                    }
                  //For Every two objects
                  //OtherObject otherObject = new OtherObject(object1, object2);
                }
            }
         }
```

But what I want it to do is to take every two SomeObject created with a name and a value to create a OtherObject that contains two someObject.

Comment: Did you try to read your XML file with XMLDocument.SelectNodes() method - that way you would get a list of XML nodes, and you could manipulate them much easier then with XmlTextReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you really want to do is create an `OtherObject` for each instance of the `Head` element, with the child objects representing the child `Node` elements.

Something like this should work:

```
XmlDocument oXml = new XmlDocument();
oXml.Load(Path);

//Get a list of Head nodes. For each one of these, create an `OtherObject`
XmlNodeList headNodes = oXml.SelectNodes("//Head");

foreach(XmlNode headNode in headNodes)
{
    //Get a list of the child 'Node' nodes
    XmlNodeList childNodes = headNode.SelectNodes("./Node");

    if(childNodes.Count == 2)
    {
       Object firstObject = new Object() { 
                                            Name = childNodes[0].Attributes["Name"].Value,
                                            Key = childNodes[0].Attributes["Key"].Value 
                                         };

       Object secondObject = new Object() { 
                                            Name = childNodes[1].Attributes["Name"].Value,
                                            Key = childNodes[1].Attributes["Key"].Value 
                                         };                                      

        OtherObject oOther = new OtherObject(firstObject, secondObject);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Linq-To-Xml](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564) instead